# .DS_Store file is magically copied to my server?

Tags: bash, macos, scp

This is mind boggling.  I use the script below to setup my server and I saw that while performing scp, some how the OSX .DS_Store file was being copied as well:

[image]

```
instDirect(){

   # hooks
   scp -r ~/root/config/git/hooks $user1@$domain1:~/root.git

   # private
   scp -r ~/root/web/source/php/_private.php $user1@$domain1:~/public_html/web/source/php/_private.php
   scp -r ~/root/web/source/js/_private.js $user1@$domain1:~/public_html/web/source/js/_private.js
   scp -r ~/root/web/source/htm/_private.htm $user1@$domain1:~/public_html/web/source/htm/_private.htm
   scp -r ~/root/config/bash/_private.sh $user1@$domain1:~/public_html/config/bash/_private.sh

   # scp -r ~/root/web/source/php/class.DBCredentials.php $user1@$domain1:~/public_html/web/source/php/class.DBCredentials.php
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Presumably it's being copied for the same reason that the `post-receive` and `pre-receive` files are being copied - because they're in the `hooks` directory.

Is your real question, then, "why is there a `.DS_Store` file in the `hooks` directory?"  If so, the answer is probably "because somebody opened it in the Finder and the Finder decided to store some state there so that it shows up similarly the next time somebody goes there in the Finder".

Comment: oddly Sublime was not showing some hidden files ( it shows other ), but Finder did.